# Metaplex Candy machine mainnet NFT depoly issue

Tags: upload, solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

I have made Solana NFT using Metaplex Candy Machine.

I have uploaded 1000 NFT. But In candy machine UI, shows available count is 985.

I lost 15 NFTs.

Also, if I click Mint Button, the count was reduced to 3 at once. and can't see NFT on my phantom wallet.

It worked on devnet perfectly, but after deploying mainnet, it occurred above error.

Please help me with this issue. how to fix this?.

I can't retrieve the lost NFTs?

Comment: I think this problem happened because the price is free.
so bots take it.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen this exact error but it could be because you did not run the verify_upload cmd after you uploaded.

Source:
https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/verify-upload

This is always recommended as network issues can cause some transactions to fail in large uploads and the CLI won't retry if they fail. The only way to confirm they are all uploaded is

```
ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts verify_upload -e devnet -k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json -c example
```

If this fails with:
`Error: not all NFTs checked out. check out logs above for details`
then just rerun the upload cmd and verify again until it outputs
`Ready to deploy!`

Comment: yeah. I solved the issue. my nft was free, so NFT mint bot could be buy my nft.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the deployment of NFTs multiple times until it is okay.